# Scala: Pass function A as a parameter through function B which B declare an implicit parameter for function A

Tags: scala, implicit

Suppose I have 2 methods, A, B, and 4 classes, C, D, E, T.

```
def A(c: C)(implicit t: Request[T]): D { ... }

def B(fn: C => D): E {
  implicit val t // I have to declare implicit val for A here
  fn(c)
  ...
}
```

Then I want to call method B with A as a parameter

```
B(A)
```

But there is an error "Cannot find any HTTP Request here" at line B(A)

I just want to pass function A like a parameter to be executed in method B, not when I Call method B.

I tried declaring t explicitly like this, it works

```
def A(c: C, t: Request[T]): D { ... }

def B(fn: C => D): E {
  fn(c, t)
  ...
}
```

But I really want to make it implicit

Is there a way to do this??

Comment: Where is `T` coming from? I don't see it declared anywhere.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Thanks. I forgot to put it in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `B(A)` at call site, something like

```
def B(fn: C => Request[T] => D): E = {
  val t = ... // no point making it implicit unless you use it elsewhere
  fn(c)(t)
  ...
}
```

should work (I can't check at the moment, but if it doesn't, try `B(A _)` as well).

But you still lose implicitness inside `B`. To avoid this, you would need [implicit function types](http://dotty.epfl.ch/blog/2016/12/05/implicit-function-types.html), which current Scala doesn't support.

Comment: It works. Actually, I have a function in fn which uses t as an implicit parameter, that's why I need it to be implicit. Btw this also helps me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? Your implicit needs to be in scope when you call A, so I think this will work:

```
def A(c: C)(implicit t: Request[T]): D { ... }

def B(fn: C => D)(implicit t: Request[T]): E {
  fn(c)
  ...
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I need to declare implicit val for method A inside method B, so I don't have any implicit declared in a scope when I call B(A) but I also don't want method A to be executed at the line B(A). I think that it should work because I just pass method A at the line B(A) and I will call A when I declare implicit val inside method B.